# Which data structure would you use? (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hashmap

I have a file contains the following data for telephone operator

`operator 1
1    0.92
44   0.5
46   0.2
467  1.0
48   1.2`

And so on...

which data structure would you use in case of thousands of data per operator and thousands of operators

**Array list of operator objects where each object has hash map for key value**
or 
**Array list of operator objects where each operator has tree map or key value**

I am concerns about the memory in first then about the performance.
if you have more efficient data structure please suggest it.

Comment: I'd use a database.

Comment: I want to do some calculation on data that is why I want to use data structure

Comment: Is the data to be used for the calculation and then discarded? Also, can you give some more details on the calculations you want to perform?

Comment: no, I must have the data in memory as long as the program run

Comment: Databases can be used for calculating things.

Comment: ...or b-tree. Worst case complexity is: space - O(n), search, insert and delete - O(log n)

Comment: you array list of operator and each has b-tree

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a multimap. Guava has an implementation: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html. Apache commons has one too, I think.

Here is the example from the javadoc:

---

The following code:

```
   ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
   for (President pres : US_PRESIDENTS_IN_ORDER) {
     multimap.put(pres.firstName(), pres.lastName());
   }
   for (String firstName : multimap.keySet()) {
     List<String> lastNames = multimap.get(firstName);
     out.println(firstName + ": " + lastNames);
   }
```

... produces output such as:

```
   Zachary: [Taylor]
   John: [Adams, Adams, Tyler, Kennedy] 
   George: [Washington, Bush, Bush]
   Grover: [Cleveland, Cleveland]
```